# WPF Richtextbox resizing performance

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have a richtextbox with a flowdocument like this:

```
var mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
var para = new Paragraph();
para.Inlines.Add(textBlock1);
para.Inlines.Add(textBlock2);
para.Inlines.Add(textBlock3);
mcFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
richTextBox1.Document = mcFlowDoc;
```

When I resize the window, there is a small delay in rendering, especially when the number of textblocks is larger (30+) and there is always some flicker.

Is there a way to make resizing faster and smoother?

Answer (score 0):

In our WPF code, we ran into problems when we started using `RichTextBox` intensively. Not specifically render problems, mostly excessive memory use.

The solution I adopted may also help you: We rendered the document without `RichTextBox`. You can convert the context of a `RichTextBox` to readonly WPF `TextBlock`.

When the user selects the control, we replace the `TextBlock` with a `RichTextBox` with the same content.

We wrapped the above behavior in a custom control. There is also some tweaking involved to get the `TextBlock` to render identical to `RichTextBox` (mostly margin/padding).

Comment: @Jerry: sorry for not responding sooner. It is a pity it does not work. It is interesting though. It could be that it's the word wrap algorith that is taking much time. Or perhaps your layout is "costly" maybe due to your edit controls size being dependent on their content where they could be fixed size.